# My registered accounts in herokuapp is not shown in django admin

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have created a django app and deployed it in Heroku.

The web app works fine and the user registration and login works too.

But when I open the django admin site it doesn't show the latest registered account. I have asked a few people to test my system so surely, there will be a few new accounts but the only accounts there were the ones I tested with a dummy account before deploying in heroku.

This is my `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
```

`settings.py`

```
"""
Django settings for sentiment_emotion_analysis project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""


import os
# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "sentiment.settings")

# import django
# django.setup()

# from django.core.management import call_command

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
       messages.DEBUG: 'alert-debug',
       messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
       messages.SUCCESS: 'success',
       messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
       messages.ERROR: 'danger',
}


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'g&x!0fjh8c8)e_-z@gs1^lbngvqwk2(o3s(5zg!o&woxdsu_un'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['sentymeter.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'sentiment',
   'user',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   
   'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sentiment_emotion_analysis.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
   {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
       'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
       'APP_DIRS': True,
       'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',
               'django.template.context_processors.request',
               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
           ],
       },
   },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sentiment_emotion_analysis.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
   }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
   {
       'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
   },
   {
       'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
   },
   {
       'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
   },
   {
       'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
   },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

MODELS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sentiment/models')
```

How to I solve this issue?

Comment: You havent registered any model in your admins.py. Its blank. Also models.py and views,py handling the registration would be useful

Comment: You shouldn't use sqlite when deploying to heroku, because it can be deleted. Use their postgresql free tier for your database

Comment: I see, how can I change the database to postgresql?